# Zend framework: Ajax is not working when i am submitting the form from fancybox in zend framework

Tags: javascript, ajax, zend-framework

My form open in a fancybox when i am submitting the form than data will not echo in controller,My script is not working on click event

-Here is my script code in which i use a ajax to send the post data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Q = jQuery.noConflict();
    Q(document).ready(
        function(){
            Q("#button_submit").click(function() { //
               alert('ok'); //alert is not working
                var name = Q('#nam').val();
                var description = Q('#description').val();
                if (name != '' && description!='') {
                    jquery.post('transaction/add', 
                                {'name' : name, 'description' : description }, 
                                function (respond) {
                                    alert("ok");           
                                }
                            );
                  }    
            });
        });
</script>
```

-here is my HTML code which contain the form. This form open in a fancy box

```
<form method="post" id="add-form" name="add-form" class="add-form">
                    <div class="main_form">
                        <table id="option-table">
                            <tr>
                                <td><label class="lable1">Name:</label></td>
                                  <td> <input type="text" name="nam" id="nam" />

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label class="lable1">Description:</label></td>
                                    <td><textarea id="description" name="description" rows="8" cols="45"></textarea>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                </td>

                                <td id="table_submit_td">
                                <input type="submit" id="button_submit_fancy" class="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
                                <input type="submit" id="button_reset" class="button" name="Reset" value="Reset" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                        </table> 
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: show the code where you have `button_submit` in HTML

Comment: Any one have a suggestion ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML, the button ID is `button_submit_fancy` not `button_submit`. Change it in one of the code - JS or HTML.